# Google Apps Script: How to encode the "parameters" param in the Execution API

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to pass some arguments to a script that is deployed as API executable. Unfortunately, for the language I use, there is no Google client library. So I have to construct the `POST` request myself. Everything is fine except that I can't figure out how to encode the `parameters` param. The request body must be `URL` encoded so I tried all of these but none works:

```
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters=aaa
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters="aaa"
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters=["aaa"]
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters[]="aaa"
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters=%22aaa%22
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters=%5B%22aaa%22%5D
function=generateDoc&devMode=true&parameters%5B%5D=%22aaa%22
```

And as a result my script function doesn't see the passed argument. Reports `undefined`. Please, help! Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share some code or if possible share google app script, and your request code. Also please clarify that are you sending post message to google stand alone script deployed as web app? and listening to the request using doGet() and doPost() handlers?

Comment: No, I am not sending a post message to a script deployed as web app but to a script deployed as `API executable`. BTW, I found the answer - the body must be `JSON` encoded and not `URL` encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - the entire request must be `JSON` encoded and then not `URL` encoded. Also `application/json` content type must be supplied. This request works for me

`{"function":"generateDoc","devMode":true,"parameters":["aaa"]}﻿`

For a discussion on Google+ https://plus.google.com/116965811397164811393/posts/ECkp2E6kU1a